# Insert data into a table from anothe table in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have two equal Oracle tables which have same column names.

1) DoctorProfile_New
2) DoctorProfile_Old

Both tables share the same structure as follows.

```
DOCREGNO      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
DOCCATOGARY          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
ANAME1                      VARCHAR2(50)
ANAME2                      VARCHAR2(50)
ANAME3                      VARCHAR2(50)
ANAME4                      VARCHAR2(50)
ANAME5                      VARCHAR2(50)
ANAME6                      VARCHAR2(50)
ANAME7                      VARCHAR2(50)
ANAME8                      VARCHAR2(50)
ANAME9                      VARCHAR2(50)
AGENDER                     VARCHAR2(2)
ARESCTOWN                   VARCHAR2(100)
DOCRCODE                     NUMBER
```

What I need to do is insert all the data from table **DoctorProfile_Old** to **DoctorProfile_New**.
The only difference is for the column `DOCREGNO`, I have to insert new hard coded value.

```
insert into DoctorProfile_New
(
DOCREGNO,       
DOCCATOGARY,    
ANAME1,         
ANAME2,         
ANAME3,         
ANAME4,         
ANAME5,         
ANAME6,         
ANAME7,         
ANAME8,         
ANAME9,         
AGENDER,        
ARESCTOWN
)
values
('000081',
(
select 
DOCCATOGARY,    
ANAME1,         
ANAME2,
ANAME3,         
ANAME4,         
ANAME5,         
ANAME6,
ANAME7,         
ANAME8,         
ANAME9,         
AGENDER,        
ARESCTOWN 
from DoctorProfile_Old  WHERE DOCREGNO='T07004'
)
)
```

I tried the above query and it always gives the Oracle error 
`ORA-00947: not enough values`

Comment: You need to write a PL/SQL procedure to achieve this.

Comment: @learningloop - Why do you need pl/sql? It's just a syntax error with the select part of the insert statement.

Comment: @booyaa I don't think `DOCREGNO` is supposed to take fixed number. So, till the number of rows in `DoctorProfile_Old` there needs a logic to automate the generation, unless the user wants to type it out manually.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
insert into DoctorProfile_New
(DOCREGNO,DOCCATOGARY,ANAME1,ANAME2,ANAME3,ANAME4,ANAME5,ANAME6,ANAME7,ANAME8,ANAME9,AGENDER,ARESCTOWN)
select '000081' as DOCREGNO, DOCCATOGARY,ANAME1,ANAME2,ANAME3,ANAME4,ANAME5,ANAME6,ANAME7,ANAME8,ANAME9,AGENDER,ARESCTOWN from DoctorProfile_Old  WHERE DOCREGNO='T07004';
```

If you want to insert DOCREGNO automatically instead of hard coated value, you should create trigger and use sequence value.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DoctorProfile_New_TRG
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON DoctorProfile_New
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    if :new.DOCREGNO is null then
        select lpad(some_sequence.nextval, 6, '0') into :new.DOCREGNO from dual;
    end if;

END;
```

Insert all data from DoctorProfile_Old

```
insert into DoctorProfile_New
(DOCREGNO,DOCCATOGARY,ANAME1,ANAME2,ANAME3,ANAME4,ANAME5,ANAME6,ANAME7,ANAME8,ANAME9,AGENDER,ARESCTOWN)
select null,DOCCATOGARY,ANAME1,ANAME2,ANAME3,ANAME4,ANAME5,ANAME6,ANAME7,ANAME8,ANAME9,AGENDER,ARESCTOWN from DoctorProfile_Old;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `insert select` to do this;

```
insert into DoctorProfile_New (
    DOCREGNO,       
    DOCCATOGARY,    
    ANAME1,         
    ANAME2,         
    ANAME3,         
    ANAME4,         
    ANAME5,         
    ANAME6,         
    ANAME7,         
    ANAME8,         
    ANAME9,         
    AGENDER,        
    ARESCTOWN
)
select 
    '000081',
    DOCCATOGARY,    
    ANAME1,         
    ANAME2,
    ANAME3,         
    ANAME4,         
    ANAME5,         
    ANAME6,
    ANAME7,         
    ANAME8,         
    ANAME9,         
    AGENDER,        
    ARESCTOWN 
from DoctorProfile_Old  
WHERE DOCREGNO='T07004';
```